# Creating responsive eye focus icon

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make responsive colored eye focus icon, but so far all I've tried has been unsuccessful.

I was trying to somewhat replicate the colors of a real eye.
I used border, box shadow, to get the colors, but that part is not scaling. Tried with outline too, but failed as well, that one wasn't even round.

The height of the div is currently static, but I would like it to be responsive. So the whole eye scales properly across different sizes.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="paragraph eye-focus">
  <div class="eye1" width="80%">
    <div class="eye2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.eye1 {
  height: 200px;
  height: calc(attr(width) / 2.5);
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.eye2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 8%;
  height: 12%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.5em solid #a50;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5em #080;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 45%;
}

.eye-focus {
  position: relative;
}
```

jsfiddle if you'd prefer https://jsfiddle.net/xcxdp92q/

Comment: Have you considered creating an SVG image instead?

Comment: Try converting the width and height units to `vw`. `vw` is similar to the percentage but to the viewport. I started but couldn't finish it, have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/xcxdp92q/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to put my solution out there.
You can use `background radial-gradient` to create the eye in a single element.
When adding padding in %, it is based on the width of the element. Use that to your advantage to make it responsive. If padding equals width, the element will be a square.

```css
.eye-focus {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 30% 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #000 8%, #a50 8%, #0b0 17%, #080 33%, transparent 33%);
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
  <div class="eye-focus"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8ernmyk/)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only supporting browsers that [support gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) (and current browsers most do) then you can just use one div and do all the colors in a radial gradient. I used `vw` to size it like Suthan Bala suggested in their comment.

```css
body {
  background: #EEE;
}

.eye {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #000000 17%, #aa5500 18%, #008800 40%, #ffffff 41%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #000000 17%, #aa5500 18%, #008800 40%, #ffffff 41%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #000000 17%, #aa5500 18%, #008800 40%, #ffffff 41%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
  width: 35vw;
  height: 35vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="eye">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

I used the [Color Gradient Generator by Colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Comment: Not quite. Firstly the eye can get much bigger than what I need it to be, and also a lot smaller. It is also in a circle shape.

Comment: @user82975 - If you have size constraints then those need to be in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS:

```
.eye1 {
  height: 4vw;
  width: 4vw;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.eye2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 6vw;
  height: 6vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1em solid #a50;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3vw #080;
  position: relative;
  top: 8vw;
  left: 43%;
}

.eye-focus {
  position: relative;
}
```

I've been using `vw` a lot lately (for a year now).  Very handy!

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the problem.  Please check this forked JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zjorge/a3zz3gfn/

Comment: That's exactly the same as mine.