# Adding corners to a eye shaped element

Tags: html, css

I have this eye shaped element here

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
.eye-focus {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 30% 0 0 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #000 8%, #a50 8%, #0b0 18%, #080 35%, #fff 35%);
  position: relative;
}

.eye-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -4%; top: 32%;
  border-right: 2em solid white;
  border-bottom: 2em solid transparent;
  border-top: 2em solid transparent;
}

.eye-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: -4%; top: 32%;
  border-left: 2em solid white;
  border-bottom: 2em solid transparent;
  border-top: 2em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
  <div class="eye-focus">
    <div class="eye-left"></div>
    <div class="eye-right"></div>
  </div>
  my paragraph text
</div>
```

jsfiddle if you'd prefer: https://jsfiddle.net/wneupyr4/

I've tried many things and none gave me the result I wanted.

I started reading into pseudo elements, but those are pretty new to me. so I couldn't do much, if some at all.

The basic concept is that those edges will make the whole eye look even more like a real one, if they will stay centered.

Comment: How do you add corners to a circle? Can you elaborate on what your desired effect?

Comment: A real eye is not really an ellipse, it's more of a pointy ellipse.

Comment: Apologies! The monitor I was viewing your snippet on has horrible color contrast, I couldn't even see the white part until now - I was only able to see the pupil portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rotate the div 45deg, you can easily get the sharp edges on the sides.
First make it a square, by putting the `width` and `padding-top`(or bottom) be the same value.
Then use `transform: rotate(45deg)` to rotate it. And finally `border-radius` of 100% to top and bottom borders to retain the eye shape.
Additionally you can use a negative margin to "cut" some of the size we get when rotating (there is a bigger distance diagonally).

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
.eye-focus {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 55%;
  padding-top: 55%;
  margin: -10% auto; /* negative margin to account for the rotation */
  border-radius: 100% 0;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #000 8%, #a50 8%, #0b0 18%, #080 35%, #fff 35%);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph">
  <div class="eye-focus"></div>
  <div class="ptext">my paragraph text</div>
</div>
```

### [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w19231rL/)

Comment: Thanks pol, looks great, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Tested and works nicely on the site, the icon doesn't go past the main container on desktop, and doesn't shrink too far. Thanks for the explanation too, that helped me understand greatly.

Answer (score 1):

To make an eye or a "pointy ellipse" or "football" or "stewie head", you can just use `border-radius` on 2 opposite corners, leave the other corners alone, then rotate the eye.

```css
.eye {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0; /* to position/keep the elemen on the page after rotation. use this as you see fit */
}
```

```html
<div class="eye"></div>
```

Comment: But this loses the responsiveness.

Comment: 10vw seems too small. But when increasing to a normal size on a laptop, the div exceeds the main container which is also responsive on the website. It makes the eye overflow out of the main div on a desktop, on an even wider screen it is even worse. Same thing would be when decreasing. The eye should be retained at about 75% of the width of the container, no matter the browser size.

Comment: @user82975 then use different widths/heights :) Here it is in your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wneupyr4/1/

Comment: Doesn't really work for me to have it based on the browser size, it should rather be the container size. You've got a + for effort, but using percentage is better for me. I thought the percentage used in the questions there should have been enough, but maybe I should have explained a bit more.

Comment: @user82975 didn't know you had these requirements. Just showing you it can be done. I assumed you would adapt the height/width as you saw fit https://jsfiddle.net/wneupyr4/2/

Comment: Yeah, that's basically pol's answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user82975 heads up you never accepted an answer on your previous question about this. pol helped you out there, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545712/creating-responsive-eye-focus-icon